# showing table with specefic element

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

i have a table full of object(type) when i click "liste des vihicules" i'de like to go to a table full of obeject(vehicule) with this condition:
vihicule.nom_type=type.nom_type
[image]

to do this i used this code

```
////go to vehicule list
 @RequestMapping(value="/liste/{nom_type}")
 public String listvih(@PathVariable(value = "nom_type") String nom_type, Model model) {


     List<Vihicule> l = vihiculeRepository.findAll();
     List<Vihicule> l1= null;
    for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++) 
    {    if(l.get(i).getNom_type()==nom_type)
        {
          l1.add(i, l.get(i));
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("v", l1);
   return  "liste";

    }
```

but it always show an emty table. what could be the problem, please help

update: i did some changes in the code and now everything work fine

```
@RequestMapping(value="/liste/{nom_type}")
public String listvih(@PathVariable(value = "nom_type") String nom_type, Model model) {

List<Vihicule> l =vihiculeRepository.findAll();
List<Vihicule> l1 = new ArrayList<Vihicule>();
        for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
        {
        if(l.get(i).getNom_type().equals(nom_type))

        {int j=0;
            l1.add(j, l.get(i));
            j++;
        }

        }
 model.addAttribute("v",l1);
 return  "liste";

}
```

Comment: The code you've posted throws a `NullPointerException` in the line that says `li.add(i, l.get(i));` since you never initialised l1. It seems as if you don't have an error, so I'd say that `findAll` returns an empty list.

Comment: But there's more to this: why not querying the repo to just return objects with `getNom_type().equals(nom_type)`? Also having underscores in variable names is not encouraged in Java.

Comment: Also use an iterator to go over the list and use `equals` instead of the equals for the string. recommendation: learn java basics before doing a deep dive into frameworks.

Comment: thank you for your help, actually i genched the null by this:List<Vihicule> l1 = new ArrayList<Vihicule>(); it works fine now blease check the update

Comment: you know that the variable `j` does nothing, right?

Comment: it's the index of list l1